# Microsoft OneNote files in the future

Tags: compatibility, microsoft-onenote, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I'm holding information on Microsoft OneNote files that i pretend to use later on, even like 30-40 years in the future.

I will be always backing up those files, and i will go keeping them on different pendrives and hard-drives.

I was thinking what might prevent me from accessing them in the future.

Is there any chance that the distribution of microsoft onenote will stop and maybe the new Operational Systems won't support the nowadays current Microsoft OneNote ?

Is there any chance that these files will go corrupt with time ? Or maybe get some error, that might prevent me from visualizing them in the future ?

Is there any preventive measure i can take ?

Comment: Yes;  Its entirely possible OneNote development will be discontinued in the future.  So before that development is stopped which will be announced in the future convert the file to a format that will be supported further into the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance that the distribution of microsoft onenote will stop and maybe the new Operational Systems won't support the nowadays current Microsoft OneNote ?

Yes.  This is a long-standing problem for archiving data, with no real answer.  Companies change their products, and go out of business.

Think of similar: Many companies backup archives to tape.  In 40 years will you be able to get a working drive for that format of tape?  Will the software you used still work with a modern operating system?  Does the current version of the backup software you used still read the old file format? Is the company even still in business if you need help?

> Is there any chance that these files will go corrupt with time ? Or maybe get some error, that might prevent me from visualizing them in the future ?

Yes. How much of a chance depends on the medium used for storage, and where/how they are stored.  Not to mention possibilities like fires, floods, earthquakes, etc. at any one location.

> Is there any preventive measure i can take ?

Yes, use a more standardized format for saving your notes, like Plain-text.  Also, keep multiple copies and *regularly test* your backups to ensure they are still functioning.

Comment: Also, copy to fresh media roughly every five years.  If the media format is losing popularity and being replaced by a newer format, migrate a copy to the newer format.

Comment: If your notes have data that is not suited to plaintext (ie, graphics) you might try putting them into PDF/A format (a PDF format specifically intended for long term storage).  Also consider using a cloud storage company like DropBox or OneDrive for additional redundancy, independent of failing media (though still susceptible to failing business).  OneNote is specifically geared to use OneDrive, so the two could be easily used together.

Comment: Of course if OneNote no longer exists then OneDrive doesn't exist.  Dropbox might not be around in 30 years.  We cannot even predict if the PDF format will be around, although due to the age and it being an open standard, you can always implement your own reader in 2044.